# Excel - determine average using 1/2 value for flagged cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a way to calculate an average of a column of numbers using 1/2 the value for cells that are flagged by an asterisk in an adjoining column without having to insert a separate column?

Comment: could you give a data example, so your source and your goal is more clear?

Answer (score 3):

If your numbers are in `ColumnA` (say rows 1:10 and the asterisks are in `ColumnB`, use `=(SUM(A1:A10)-SUMIF(B1:B10,"*",A1:A10)/2)/COUNT(A1:A10)`

Comment: +1 This works fine, I think, as long as B1:B10 has either blanks or asterisk - if there is other text in that range then "*" criterion will also count those, as that works as a wildcard here

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct pnuts, I didn't think of that

Answer (score 3):

This "array formula" should do what you want

`=AVERAGE(A1:A10/IF(B1:B10="*",2,1))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` so that curly braces like { and } appear around the formula in the formula bar

Comment: I know what you mean, I was just thinking about the wildcard issue but you answered that one.......